# How can you format each row from a pivot table to display transposed with the headers repeating themselves?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, pivot-table, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

From a pivot table, I am attempting to take each row of data and format it transposed with the headers from the pivot table present in each instance. [Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18PjojStcWUjzTwEdevRRRPeroc0pBy8_Om0ySZOxVrQ/edit#gid=1219166940) to a Google Sheet that has a sample pivot table as well as a sample of how I need to format the data.

[Screenshot of Pivot Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7vH1.jpg)

[Screenshot of how I am attempting to format the data from the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcv5n.jpg)

Comment: What you are expecting as OUTPUT is possible using the Case ID but one after another and the involve method would be formula,, I don't think that PT can produce such a clean output format.. possibly Power BI or others like ZOHO analytics can do this or even the Fuzzy Lookup!!

Comment: It looks like you just need to unpivot your source data, and add a blank row between each group.  Easy to do in Excel with Power Query.  Not sure about sheets, though.  But I'm sure if you search, you'll find something.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whther following suggestion about PowerQuery is helpful.

Choose the whole data and import them to Excel Power Query.

Then press Ctrl + A, go to File tab > Any column group > Unpivot Columns. Then you would get the result like image below.

[image]